# How can I replicate Perl's unpack functionality in C#?

Tags: c#, perl, unpack

I am trying to recreate a Perl script in C# but have a problem creating a checksum value that a target system needs.

In Perl this checksum is calculated using the `unpack` function:

```
while (<PACKAGE>) {
    $checksum += unpack("%32C*", $_);
}
$checksum %= 32767;
close(PACKAGE);
```

where `PACKAGE` is the .tar file input stream

I need to replicate this in C# but can't find a means of replicating that `unpack` function.

All help appreciated!

(I know there are much better checksum calculations available but can't change target system so can't change calculation)

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a library in Mono called [DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert) that was written to provide facilities similar to Perl's pack/unpack.  Does this do what you need?

Comment: The OP has spammed the internet with this question. Clearly he is not looking for answers as I already suggested your advice to him on CodeProject.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot install the dataconvert library on the server  we are using so I am looking for alternatives. I wouldn't say asking the question on 7 forums is spamming the internet-my assumption was that each forum would have different readers and I would get different responses from each..

Answer (score 4):

Perkl's unpack is described [here](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlfunc/unpack.html) and [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/plugins/wp-downloadMonitor/user_uploads/perl.pack.unpack.printf.cheat.sheet.pdf).  From that you should be able to write an equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement Mitch Wheat's comment, here's a Java implementation (which does a single block only). I'm sure you'll find a way to convert it into C#, and to do multiple blocks.

```
int sum = 0;
for (byte b : buffer) {
    sum += (int) b & 255;
}
return sum % 32767;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my testing here, unpack with %32C appears to be the additive sum of the bytes, limited to 32 bits.

```
print unpack("%32C*", 'A');
65
print unpack("%32C*", 'AA');
130
```

It shouldn't be hard to reproduce that.

Comment: yeah, the problem I seem to have is because the file is a tar it has non-standard ascii characters in there and these throw up different results in the perl script and the C# script I put together.  Just can't determine why.

Comment: Are you ensuring binary mode in both cases? Regardless of the "tar" type of file format, reading one byte at a time in binary (non-translated or non-ASCII) mode should give the same bytes regardless of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of Chris Jester-Young and piCookie, I developed the following function. I hope you find it useful.

```
int fileCheckSum(const char *fileName)
{
   FILE *fp;
   long fileSize;
   char *fileBuffer;
   size_t result;
   int sum = 0;
   long index;

   fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      fputs ("File error",stderr); 
      exit (1);
   }

   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
   fileSize = ftell(fp);
   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

   fileBuffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * fileSize);   
   if (fileBuffer == NULL)
   {
      fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
      exit (2);
   }

   result = fread(fileBuffer, 1, fileSize, fp);   
   if (result != fileSize)
   {
      fputs ("Reading error", stderr);
      if (fileBuffer != NULL)
         free(fileBuffer);

      exit (3);
   }

   for (index = 0; index < fileSize; index++)
   {
      sum += fileBuffer[index] & 255;
   }

   fclose(fp);
   if (fileBuffer != NULL)
      free(fileBuffer);

   return sum % 32767;  
}
```